# Should I use speech marks for sounds?

Tags: speech, onomatopoeia, sounds

If I were to describe a sudden sound, in this example: Boom!
Were I to put it in speech marks: "Boom!" 
Just like in a dialogue, or to do something else, in that case what?

Comment: Unless someone is *saying,* “Boom”, don’t put it in quotes.

Comment: Alright, but if we say the sound is made of a meteor hitting the ground, I should use some kind of punctuation right?

Comment: You might *choose* to put that in italics:  *Boom!*  The meteor cratered into the ground producing a shock wave that knocked him to the ground.

Comment: *"Bang!" went the tire.*  is perfectly valid.

Comment: @HotLicks I tried looking for examples where the object making the noise is referred to. Here are three examples that refute your comment: [1](http://bit.ly/2QpTFNo), [2](http://bit.ly/2QpxxTc), and [this book intentionally leaves out the quotation marks in between other segments of speech](http://bit.ly/2QnTYbp). 

[This book is in favour](http://bit.ly/2QoZquM), but that does refer to a person making the noise, rather than an inanimate object.

(I had to shorten the URLs because otherwise the comment would be over the character limit.)

Comment: Using sound effects like this seems more fitting for comic books than for formal writing. In the latter you might say "it made a loud boom" or "a booming sound".

Comment: @Jim Please make that an answer.

Comment: Suppose it is an animal that makes the sound eg. "Woof woof" said the dog. What do you do then?

Answer (score 0):

Quotation marks should not be used for emphasis, only to indicate something that is spoken or quoted.

Comment: What should be used for emphasis?

Comment: Italics, as Jim said.

Comment: @sumelic If you can't use italics, bold or underline; I'd suggest using `*` or `_` "around" the emphasized text...  It's often used in plain text-files for emphasis.  Strictly speaking; `/` = italics, `*`= bold and `_` = underscored; but I think most prefer to use either `*` or `_`, and then as just "emphasized".  So putting `Boom!` between two `*` should work...

Comment: @BaardKopperud that only applies to a coding context, not a WYSIWIG context.

Comment: Uh, the quotation marks are used to indicate the sound made by something.  Just because it's not human doesn't mean it can't be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, do not. An exception being when you personify the object, as was mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your answer could be improved by explaining a bit more and providing references. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

and if you're trying to personify something like a cupboard door swinging you could creatively use "squeak!" instead of squeak! to give it more charecter...But thats an exception.